# Better to |> ignore or return ()

Tags: f#

So this is just a curiosity question.

If I want to return unit, which is better practice?

```
|> ignore
```

or

```
()
```

There's probably other ways as well. I just want to know what's best, considering these:

- What is most performant
- What is best practice for a production environment
- What is most readable for long term maintanance

Comment: Why are you even concerned about performance? I mean how many million calls to ignore would be needed to be even noticeable. On top I would assume that the implementation looks something like this `let inline ignore (x:'a) = ()`
Second why are you making any differences between prod and dev/testing?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I respectfully disagree. Attention to details, how things work and why, allows you to reduce code rot which reduces overall cost.

Comment: Obviously this is your call - Thou I agree with @FyodorSoikin. I wouldn't spend any time on this until a) a problem becomes known and b) I have measured what effectively causes given problem. But again your decision

Comment: @robkuz and FyodorSoikin: You've jumped on Anthony unfairly here. He's already stated that this is from curiosity, so it's not an attempt at optimisation. So what if the difference wouldn't matter 99.99% of the time even if the function was not inlined? That's just part of the answer to this question. Sorry about that Anthony, and welcome to F# :)

Comment: Bigger excerpt from Knuth: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." 

He is saying that in most cases optimization gives little benefits but in critical code paths we should optimize. Sane and less dogmatic

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox yeah you are right. I missed the couriosity part at the beginning.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox there was a comment from Anthony (right after robkuz's first one) explicitly stating that he was looking to optimize this. That comment is now gone, and now our subsequent comments look much worse than they did at the time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you are comparing things that are not quite comparable here. The `()` value lets you create the unit value, while `|> ignore` is what you can use to ignore some other result. The two are not exactly the same:

If you are calling a function and you want to ignore the result, you can write just:

```
doStuff () |> ignore
```

But doing the same with `()` would require you to either ignore the warning:

```
doStuff () // warning: Result is ignored
()
```

... or you could assign the result to an ignore pattern `_` using `let` binding:

```
let _ = doStuff ()
()
```

So, in this case, using `ignore` is better - it is inlined, so it has no performance implications and it leads to code that is easier to read.

That said, there are cases where you just need to create a unit value and then `()` is what you need (and there is no obvious way `ignore` would let you do the same). For example:

```
match optMessage with
| Some message -> printfn "ANNOUNCEMENT: %s" message
| None -> ()
```

You could replace `()` with `42 |> ignore` to get the same result, but it would be silly!

Comment: Even if a function ended like 'doStuff() |> ignore` I might still put `()` at the end simply to make the fact that there is no result more obvious.

Answer (score 6):

`ignore` is an inlined function so both will produce exactly the same IL.

`ignore` is more explicit and therefore more readable, and that's why it exists, so you should probably prefer that.

Comment: Awesome thank you. Now that you say that I guess I could have just used ILDasm and figured it out myself :-)